# Access to queue attributes?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a number of GenerateTableFetch processors that send Flowfiles to a downstream UpdateAttributes processor. From the UpdateAttributes, the Flowfile is passed to an ExecuteSQL processor:

[image]

Is there any way to add an attribute to a flow file coming off a queue with the position of that Flowfile in the queue? For example, After I reset/clear the state for a GenerateTableFetch, I would like to know if this is the first batch of Flowfiles coming from GenerateTableFetch. I can see the position of the FlowFile in the queue, but it would nice is there's a way that I could add that as an attribute that is passed downstream.  Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is not an available feature in Apache NiFi. The position of a flowfile in a queue is dynamic, and will change as flowfiles are removed from the queue, either by downstream processing or by flowfile expiration.

If you are simply trying to determine if the queue was empty before a specific flowfile was added, your best solution at this time is probably to use an `ExecuteScript` processor to get the desired connection via the REST API, then use `FlowFileQueue#isActiveQueueEmpty()` to determine if the specified queue is currently empty, and add a boolean attribute to the flowfile indicating it is the "first of a batch" or whatever logic you want to apply.

"Batches" aren't really a NiFi concept. Is there a specific action you want to take with the "first" flowfile? Perhaps there is other logic (i.e. the `ExecuteSQL` processor hasn't operated on a flowfile in x seconds, etc.) that could trigger your desired behavior.